# Expired patent - non-payment

Tags: patent-infringement, expiration, fees, reinstatement, intervening-rights

hypothetical question. Let's assume someone else's patent has expired due to non-payment, and we release a product that that would potentially have infringed on it.

Three months later they see our product has gone live and file a petition to get the maintenance fee renewed and it gets granted.

Where does that leave us legally? When our product came out the patent was expired/invalid, and they dug it out of the grave - would we be legally safe or are we infringing once the patent fees are paid?

Comment: You should research something called "intervening rights" and get advice specific to your non-hypothetical facts from an attorney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the USPTO MPEP:

**2591    Intervening Rights in Reinstated Patents**

> Intervening rights in reinstated patents are provided by 35 U.S.C.
>   41(c)(2) which is reproduced in MPEP § 2501. No patent, the term of
>   which has been maintained as a result of the acceptance of a late
>   payment of a maintenance fee, shall abridge or affect the right of any
>   person or his or her successors in business who made, purchased,
>   imported, or used after the 6-month grace period but prior to the
>   acceptance of the late maintenance fee anything protected by the
>   patent, to continue the use or importation of, or to sell to others to
>   be used or sold, the specific things made, purchased, imported, or
>   used. A court before which such matter is in question may provide for
>   the continued manufacture, use, importation, or sale of the thing
>   made, purchased, imported, or used as specified, or for the
>   manufacture, use, importation, or sale of which substantial
>   preparation was made after the 6-month grace period but before the
>   acceptance of the late maintenance fee, and it may also provide for
>   the continued practice of any process, practiced, or for the practice
>   of which substantial preparation was made, after the 6-month grace
>   period but prior to the acceptance of the late maintenance fee, to the
>   extent and under such terms as the court deems equitable for the
>   protection of investments made or business commenced after the 6-month
>   grace period but before the acceptance of the late maintenance fee.